# My Pokemon go account has reset

Tags: pokemon-go

I just updated the Pokemon go app and it asked me to log in again and I'm back at the very start, please help!

Comment: https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/224047008

Answer (score 2):

One thing that worked for me is this solution from a [support ticket](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/224047008).

1. Either uninstall and reinstall the Pokémon GO app or sign out of your
   account (Pokémon GO>Main Menu>Settings>Sign Out)

   - NOTE: You may need    to sign out of your account twice to ensure
     proper log out before signing back in with your correct account.
2. Open Pokémon GO and select the Google login method.
3. You will be    redirected to the Safari web browser to complete the
   login process.
4. Review the email address listed in the top right corner of the page.
   Ensure that the Google account presented is the same email address
   used when you originally created your Pokémon GO account. If the email address does not match the email address used to create your Pokémon GO account, please sign out of Google and log back in with the appropriate account.
5. Touch the “Allow” button and you will be redirected back to the
   Pokémon GO app.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The way I got it to work was the remove any passwords from my phone, and to delete and redownload the app. This gave me the logon prompt again and asked me to accept the ULA again.